# how can I create a link to to add user page in salesforce using apex or visual page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to create a quick access page for shortcut links to some few settings.
example of the links i want to create include.

Manage Users
Sandbox

So when you click Manage users it will direct you to the main manage users page to create new users, etc.

I don't want to go to quick search all the time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Easiest I would say is to copy the URL(s) and create custom links on the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do is copy the url and paste into outputlink. Don't copy org domain  name ,just copy rest of the url as i shown below.

```
<apex:page  >
  <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
           <apex:outputLink value="//setup/ui/listApexTraces.apexp?retURL=%2Fui%2Fsetup%2FSetup%3Fsetupid%3DLogs&setupid=ApexDebugLogs" target="_blank">Debug Log</apex:outputLink>
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
           <apex:outputLink value="//005/e?retURL=%2F005%3FisUserEntityOverride%3D1%26retURL%3D%252Fui%252Fsetup%252FSetup%253Fsetupid%253DUsers%26setupid%3DManageUsers&isUserEntityOverride=1" target="_blank">New User</apex:outputLink>
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```